add_submenu_page add multilevel menu
Im using:
// wp-admin hotels list in sidebar
function add_custom_submenu_under_add_new() {
    $args=array(
        'post_type' => 'hotel',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => 0
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            global $post;
            add_submenu_page(
                'edit.php?post_type=hotel', // parent slug
                get_the_title($post->ID), // page title
                get_the_title($post->ID), // menu title
                'edit_posts', // capability (use the same as for editing posts)
                'post.php?post='.$post->ID.'&action=edit'
            );
        }
    } 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_submenu_under_add_new');

To add custom menu to wp-admin sidebar under custom post type (hotel). What I need to do is to add second level menu to every created item, so I can show there subpages of this CPT. Is there any way to achieve that?
